# How to make a correct ManyToMany relation with Hibernate and Kotlin? (Getting BeanCreationException)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, kotlin

I have the following code which throws the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: project, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(type)]
```

I think I am creating the @ManyToMany mapping in a wrong way. Here are the main classes in question:

```
@Entity
class Project (

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    var id : UUID? = null,

    var owner: Int,

    @get:ManyToMany(mappedBy = "project", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    var type: MutableSet<Type> = mutableSetOf()

    )
```

The second class is:

```
class Type(

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    var id: UUID? = null,

    var oldId: Int,

    var value: String,

    @get:ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @get:JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    var projects: MutableSet<Project> = mutableSetOf()
)
```

A Project can have many Types and a Type can belong to many projects. What is causing the exception?

Comment: is @entity added on class Type ?

Comment: No, that was actually the problem, thank you!

Comment: so it got resolved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Project` entity,

```
@get:ManyToMany(mappedBy = "project", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    var type: MutableSet<Type> = mutableSetOf()
```

Here, mappedBy has value `project`,

while, in `Type` entity, variable name is `projects`,

So, if you just update `Project` entity's type field as follow:

```
 @get:ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projects", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        var type: MutableSet<Type> = mutableSetOf()
```

This should work just fine. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
@get:ManyToMany
@get:JoinColumn
```

to

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinColumn
```